# what to do if tile of shower is 58.5 at top and 57.5" at bottom for door?

Tags: doors, shower

I need to install a door but the tile is off by 1" from the top to the bottom?     Is there an easy workaround for this?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: There are ways to deal with this.   It isn't as easy as telling you what to do.   Easiest thing is find a shower door that allows 1" out of plumb.   They are out there.   This is not end of world - it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is **way** out of plumb... but don't worry, there are solutions. You need a shower enclosure that has 2-piece side frames. They are designed so that the outer piece that the door(s) butt up against when closed can be adjusted by sliding them into a "U" shaped channel that attaches to the tile:

[image]

Comment: so I may be ok then?  I think each side may be off by 1/2 inch, and that added up to an inch!!! it did say 'per side' there!!!  so I may be barely ok.

Comment: @DeanHiller, since it is such a big gap, it should be easy to use a 4' level and see how bad each side is.  You could then know with relative certainty if one side was way off or if each side was off.